# Export table to CSV file without prompt

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-table

I want to have tables that I can easily export to files. In this regard I want to associate a file path and a format to tables. This page in the docs is most relevant: https://orgmode.org/manual/Built_002din-table-editor.html

I tried this to set the file path:

```
#+TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: 'data/observations.csv'
| day              | observation |
|------------------+-------------|
| <2019-11-14 Thu> | cold        |
| <2019-11-14 Thu> | warm        |
```

And then running `org-table-export` but I still get the prompt asking for a file.

I am fine with a per-file setting of the file format, i.e.:

```
# Local Variables:
# mode: org
# org-table-export-default-format: orgtbl-to-csv
# End:
```

But it would be nice to set that as well on a per table basis.

I also would like a way to run this for all tables at once (ideally in combination with `org-babel-tangle`). I'll ask another Q for that if you want the points :)

Comment: I just need tangling tables for myself. Added an alternative answer doing that.

Comment: Awesome, I'm changing the accepted answer to that one since it is exactly what the question asks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following Elisp code couples Org table export to csv/tsv with `org-babel-tangle`.

Tables with the following affiliated attribute are exported to data files on `org-babel-tangle`:
`#+ATTR_TANGLE: DATAFILE`

You can also specify the export type:
`#+ATTR_TANGLE: ("DATAFILE" "TYPE")`

```el
(defun org+-tangle-table-at-point ()
  "Tangle Org table at point.
The table is ignored if it is not preceeded by a line like:
#+ATTR_TANGLE: DATAFILE
or
#+ATTR_TANGLE: (\"DATAFILE\" \"TYPE\")"
  (interactive)
  (unless (org-at-table-p)
    (user-error "Not at Org table"))
  (let* (type
     (data (org-element-context))
     (parent (org-element-property :parent data))
     file)
    (while parent
      (setq data parent)
      (setq parent (org-element-property :parent data)))
    (when (and (setq prop (org-element-property :attr_tangle data))
           (setq file (read prop)))
      (cond
       ((symbolp file)
    (setq file (symbol-name file)))
       ((stringp file)) ;; keep it that way
       ((consp file)
    (setq type (nth 1 file)
          file (car file)))
       (t
    (user-error "Unexpected format of table to be tangled")))
      (org-table-export file (or type org-table-export-default-format))
      t)))

(defun org+-tangle-tables (fun &optional arg target-file lang)
  "Tangle Org tables in current buffer.
For around advice with `org-babel-tangle' as FUN.
See `org-babel-tangle' for the args ARG, TARGET-FILE and LANG.

Currently, only one table per file is possible."
  (cond
   ((equal arg '(4)) ;; at point
    (if (org-at-table-p)
    (org+-tangle-table-at-point)
      (funcall fun arg target-file lang)))
   ((equal arg '(16))
    (funcall fun arg target-file lang))
   (t
    (funcall fun arg target-file lang)
    (let ((table-count 0))
      (org-with-wide-buffer
       (goto-char (point-min))
       (while (re-search-forward "^[ \t\r]*|" nil t)
     (goto-char (match-beginning 0))
     (when (org+-tangle-table-at-point)
       (cl-incf table-count))
     (goto-char (org-table-end)))
       )
      (message "Tangled %d tables from %s." table-count (buffer-name))))))

(advice-add 'org-babel-tangle :around #'org+-tangle-tables)
```

Example Org source file with two exported tables:

```
#+ATTR_TANGLE: /tmp/test.dat
#+NAME: myTable
| test   | table |
| first  | row   |
| second | row   |
| third  | row   |

Some intermediate text.

Some src block:
#+BEGIN_SRC emacs-lisp :tangle /tmp/test.el
"Here I am."
#+END_SRC

#+ATTR_TANGLE: ("/tmp/test1.dat" "orgtbl-to-csv")
| another | table |
|---------+-------|
|      11 |    12 |
|      21 |    22 |
```

Answer (score 2):

The doc you linked says:

> You may also use properties `TABLE_EXPORT_FILE` and `TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT` to specify the file name and the format for table export in a subtree.

They are properties and not keywords. So you set them in the properties drawer of the subtree.

Example:

```
* Section with table
:PROPERTIES:
:TABLE_EXPORT_FILE: data/observations.csv
:TABLE_EXPORT_FORMAT: orgtbl-to-csv
:END:

| day              | observation |
|------------------+-------------|
| <2019-11-14 Thu> | cold        |
| <2019-11-14 Thu> | warm        |
```

Comment: This works. Seems counterintuitive though imo. It doesn't export the header row though...